# read connectionstring outside startup from appsetting.json in vNext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a project class (Nuget Package). I need to read in a static class without constructor my connections string to MongoDB.

**Static Class Method:**

```
        /// <summary>
        /// The default key MongoRepository will look for in the appsettings.json 
        /// </summary>
        private const string DefaultConnectionstringName = "Data:MongoDB:MongoServerSettings";

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the default connectionstring from appsettings.json
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the default connectionstring from the App.config or Web.config file.</returns>
        public static string GetDefaultConnectionString()
        {
            var config = new Configuration();
            return config.Get<string>(DefaultConnectionstringName);
        }
```

I have always null... How can I obtain the value outside the Startup.cs without using DI?

It is possible?

In my old code I could do something like that:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the default connectionstring from the App.config or Web.config file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the default connectionstring from the App.config or Web.config file.</returns>
    public static string GetDefaultConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DefaultConnectionstringName].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `var config = new Configuration();` do you use RC1 ? At RC1 must be use ConfigurationBuilder: `var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()`.

Comment: Yes @StasBoyarincev I'm usung RC1, can you please tell me what is the best way to use the ConfigurationBuilder? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Inside your startup, you should save the connection string to a static property on `Startup`

```
public class Startup
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddUserSecrets();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        ConnectionString = Configuration.Get<string>("Data:MongoDB:MongoServerSettings");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then you should be able to access it from wherever:

```
public static string GetDefaultConnectionString()
{
    return Startup.ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: It works but not in a Class Library, it works for example in my HomeController. I didn't speak about this specification... I will mark as valid by the way :)

Comment: Thanks. Gotcha. Yeah in that case you should set the value in the library from your startup project, or put it in a shared library. Best yet is refactor your code to not use statics and use DI :)

Answer (score 48):

1.ConnectionString in appsetting.json

[image]

2. Creating Singleton Instance of Configuration in Startup.cs class

[image]

3. Reading Values from Configuration Instance Using Dependency Injection [Constructor injection ]

[image]

4. Finally Output

[image]

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer. Awesome explanation.

Comment: I need to read only "Data" section from appsettings.json. How can i achieve that

Comment: Thanks -- this is a terrific answer and solved my problem exactly.

Comment: Ok. But how does ProductConcrete get instantiated?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
   public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath).AddJsonFile("config.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        var connStr = Configuration.Get("connString");
    }
```

Docs: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me. I am building a .net core 2.1 api.

I used

```
public class Startup 
{
    public static string ConnectionString {get; private set;}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("xxxxxx");
            app.UseMvc();
}
```

Then whenever i need it i call `string ConnString = Startup.ConnectionString;`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I obtain the value outside the Startup.cs without using DI? It is possible?

Yes, you can using Configuration without DI and throughout your application. But recommended way using Configuration API only in Startup and then [Using Options](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects):

> create well-factored settings objects that correspond to certain features within your application, thus following the Interface Segregation Principle (ISP) (classes depend only on the configuration settings they use)

Example using Configuration API

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Name": "Stas",
  "Surname": "Boyarincev"
}
```

Using Configuration:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var Configuration = builder.Build();

var name = Configuration.GetSection("name");
var surname = Configuration.GetSection("surname");
```

[tutorial on docs.asp.net](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) - but it a bit outdated.