# How to read values from appsettings.json inside a class in .Net 6?

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0

I want to access the values of the Configurations Variables in another class.

Here is the appsetting.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"Configurations": {
   "FirstVerificationValidationDurationMinutes": 2,
   "ResendedVerificationValidationDurationMinutes": 2,
   "JwtRegisterTokenValidationDurationMinutes": 30,
   "JwtLoginTokenValidationDurationMinutes": 30
 }
}
```

And Here I want to use **JwtLoginTokenValidationDurationMinutes**'s value (which is declared inside appsettings.json as you can see ablove) inside the class below:

```
public async Task<UserCredentialDto> JwtAuthentication(UserCredentialViewModel userCredential)
    {

        var user = await _userService.LoginUser(userCredential);

        if (user is null)
        {
            return new UserCredentialDto
            {
                Status = new StatusMaker().ErrorStatus(user.Status.Message)
            };
        }

        

        //TODO
        var _key = "This is for test";

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_key);


        //var tokenValidationDuration = HERE I NEED THE VALUE //HOW TO ACCESS VALUES FROM appsettings.json?

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(/*tokenValidationDuration*/),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);


        return new UserCredentialDto
        {
            Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
        };
    }

}
```

So how can I access values from appsettings.json ?

I tried using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration but it seems it doesn't exist in .Net 6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use appsettings.json in Asp.net core 6 Program.cs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69390676/how-to-use-appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core-6-program-cs-file)

Comment: @gsharp No it isn't

Comment: @Masoud Check out my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69390676/how-to-use-appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core-6-program-cs-file

Comment: @sajed No it's not the answer ☺

Comment: @Masoud why not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read connectionstring outside startup from appsetting.json in vNext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269106/read-connectionstring-outside-startup-from-appsetting-json-in-vnext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var JwtLoginTokenValidationDurationMinutes = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Configurations:JwtLoginTokenValidationDurationMinutes").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class Configurations
{
   public int FirstVerificationValidationDurationMinutes { get; set; }
   public int ResendedVerificationValidationDurationMinutes{ get; set; }
   public int JwtRegisterTokenValidationDurationMinutes{ get; set; }
   public int JwtLoginTokenValidationDurationMinutes{ get; set; }
}

/*
"Configurations": {
   "FirstVerificationValidationDurationMinutes": 2,
   "ResendedVerificationValidationDurationMinutes": 2,
   "JwtRegisterTokenValidationDurationMinutes": 30,
   "JwtLoginTokenValidationDurationMinutes": 30
 }
*/
```

in Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<Configuration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Configurations"));
```

this will add your class object to configuration. than you will call through `TOptions<>`

> Registers a configuration instance which TOptions will bind against.

than you should use dependency injection.

```cs
public class SomeService:IService
{
    private readonly Configurations _configurations
    public SomeService(IOptions<Configurations> configurations){
        _configurations = configurations.Value
    }

    //your code
       Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_configurations.JwtLoginTokenValidationDurationMinutes),
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the question it seems that you are talking about a regular class, not startup or program.cs, therefore you wont have access to the builder. In a regular class, you can inject an instance to the configuration class and then use it to read your settings file.

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
public ConfigurationDemoController(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

public void Function()
{
    var settingVale= _configuration.GetValue<string>("yourSettingName");
    ...;
}
```

}